# Datepicker on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datepicker

I've searched for this problem and im still struggling to fix it.

Im creating my first project on Laravel and im trying to include a datepicker on my form.

At my App.blade.php i have the scripts from jQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

And after those i have my bootstrap scripts.

Before the footer i have this script to a JS file inside my Public/src folder:

```
<script src="{{ asset('src/js/main.js') }}" defer></script>
```

At my Welcome.blade.php i have this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<form action="" class="w-50 search-form">
      <label for="">Date</label>
      <input type="text" value="2012-05-15 21:05" class="datepicker">
</form>
@endsection
```

And at that external JS file i have this:

```
$('#date').datepicker();
```

Although when i run that on browser i get this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: $.datepicker is not a function**

Can anyone give me a hint what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your JS inside $(document).ready(function() { /CODE/ });

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't included Jquery Twice ? if not, maybe try to put your main.js import before or remove it just to see if DatePicker work after that